# Were Job's declarations in Job 27 prophetic?

Tags: numbers, job

Numbers 23:7:

> And [Baalam] took up his discourse and said...

Job 27:1 (NASB):

> Job again took up his discourse and said...

In Numbers 23, Baalam's oracle was clearly prophetic. Was Job's discourse also intended in the same sense? Why the (apparently) parallel language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar phrases you see are part of the narration, and they mention nothing about prophecy. In hermeneutics, you'd need a greater reason than similar narration to identify the genre of what is being spoken.

Knowing whether the statements were prophecy or history or ideology or law, et cetera, you must look at the statements themselves.

And, if you look at the Numbers passage, that is not a prophecy either, it is a historical account.

**Numbers 23:7** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2023%3A7&version=NASB1995))

> He took up his discourse and said,
>
> “From Aram Balak has brought me,
>
> Moab’s king from the mountains of the East,
>
> ‘Come curse Jacob for me,
>
> And come, denounce Israel!’

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Also, congratulations on the new diamond :)